# How can we deploy ASP.NET Framework image in GCP without using external IP? My Application is in ASp.net Windows Form and I want to deploy it on GCP

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-platform, ip, external

aspnet has resource level errors
aspnet-10: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"412","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":412,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"If-Match","locationType":"header","message":"Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 109483663587. Add instance projects/ld-playground-pcoi/zones/us-central1-f/instances/aspnet-10 to the constraint to use external IP with it.","reason":"conditionNotMet"}],"message":"Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 109483663587. Add instance projects/ld-playground-pcoi/zones/us-central1-f/instances/aspnet-10 to the constraint to use external IP with it.","statusMessage":"Precondition Failed","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ld-playground-pcoi/zones/us-central1-f/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}

ANSWER TO ABOVE QUESTION: I think there is no way to disabled External IP with this option. An alternate approach is to get a Windows VM yourself and install whatever you need with the configuration you need (i.e. no external IP). Then, you can create an instance template from that existing VM, and create the same VM on demand without having to rely on that solution.

Comment: Can you ask a question? Explain the context,...

Comment: I am following the below link and tried to deploy the existing ASP.net application PCO to ASP.net framework image (GPC compute engine) and able to successfully deploy that to Compute engine with default network setting using my personal trial account.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-compute-engine-aspnet#0

But now I am using a client's account to deploy our Asp.net POC to the Asp.net framework image and it's giving the below error due to using external IP which is not allowed. Can we disable the external IP?

Comment: I think there is no way to disabled External IP with this option.  An alternate approach is to get a Windows VM yourself and install whatever you need with the configuration you need (i.e. no external IP). Then, you can create an instance template from that existing VM, and create the same VM on demand without having to rely on that solution.

Comment: Yes this marketplace product don't let you the choice to remove public IP on the VM. The other solution is to create an exception in the org policies to create the VM, then to delete manually the public IP and to reactivate the org policy

Comment: @MinakshiThakare Could you put as an answer to the post the solution/workaround you found to your issue? It would be helpful for other members of the community who are facing similar problems.

Comment: @Nahuel I think there is no way to disabled External IP with this option. An alternate approach is to get a Windows VM yourself and install whatever you need with the configuration you need (i.e. no external IP). Then, you can create an instance template from that existing VM, and create the same VM on demand without having to rely on that solution. –